# Title Format - Object Label instead of Value

Tags: craft3

I am trying to get the label from an object instead of its value to use as the automatic title for my entries.

For example: I have an entry that contains a dropdown with the handle exampleOne with values Item One, Item Two, etc. In the title format field I enter {{object.exampleOne}} and it outputs itemOne. It appears craft is outputting the "value" of that dropdown but I instead want it to output the "Label". Is this possible? I looked through the docs and did some googling but to no avail. I also tried {{ object.exampleOne|label }} but it failed to rename the entries.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation you're looking for: [Working with Dropdown Field Data](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dropdown-fields.html#working-with-dropdown-field-data)

You can get the label by adding `.label`, so you'll end up with `{{object.exampleOne.label}}`

The dropdown field contains a few properties:

- label
- selected
- value (default)
- valid

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.